# Is it idiomatic?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar

I said to my friend

'My heart's a stereo 
It beats for you
So listen close'

He said Yes I am ...

Is it idiomatic 
Or should he have said
Yes I am listening

Comment: I'd answer, "Okay"

Answer (score 3):

> Hurry up, or we'll be late. Are you on your way?
>   --Yes, I am [on my way].
>
> Pay attention to this tricky point. Are you paying attention?
>   --Yes, I am [paying attention].

The ellipsis is grammatical.  The question-and-answer structure leaves no doubt as to what has been omitted.

This would not be grammatical:

> Pay attention to this tricky point. Are you paying attention?
>   --Yes, I ...

Comment: I didn't say *So listen close. Are you?* His reply would work there if i had said this

Comment: An idiomatic reply would be **I am listening** which can be shortened to **I am** because a native speaker would understand from the question-and-answer that the omitted verb is LISTEN in some form, and **am** must go with the present participle LISTENING here.  It is a perfectly legitimate reply that could easily come from the mouth of any one of hundreds of millions of native speakers.

Comment: If he'd said . Yes I do. Then It would be a habitual action. right? But this would not sound right with what I said earlier

Comment: If he said, **Yes, I do** would suggest habit or practice, as you say. **do listen** is not used in contemporary English as a synonym for **am listening** (action ongoing at this moment).  There would have to be some justifying context for **I do**, such as your speaking that line to your friend every day for a week.

Comment: Or something like I already do would also work here

Comment: Not really.  *I already **am*** would be the idiomatic reply.